# Como recargar RecyclerView

Tags: android

Hola mi gente tengo una duda que me esta rompiendo la cabeza y ya me ah tomado gran parte del día. Tengo un RecyclerView en android el cual deseo que se recargue una vez que hago una acción en el adapter y no se como hacerlo. aqui les muestro parte de mi codigo. en esta parte es donde hago la llamada a la opción Eliminar la cual elimina un producto mediante una opción en el recycler view.

```
 holder.menuDesbordamientoCardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(context, holder.menuDesbordamientoCardView);
            MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.desbordamiento_cardview_producto,popup.getMenu());
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    //do your things in each of the following cases
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.eliminarProductoId:

                            Productos productos=new Productos();
                            Toast.makeText(context, holder.id.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            productos.deleteProducto(holder.id.getText().toString(),context);

                           context.startActivity(new Intent(context,Productos.class));

                            return true;

                        default:
                            return false;
                    }
                }
            });
            popup.show();
        }
    });
```

Lo siguiente que les muestro es mi método eliminar en el cual hago la acción de eliminar y no se como hacer que se cargue mi RecyclerView nuevamente.

```
public void getProductos(final Context context) { // Funcionando correctamente



    final StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, IP_ROUTE + "facturasapi/public/productos", new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            // Toast.makeText(Productos.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            JSONArray obj = null;
            ProductosModel productosModel = new ProductosModel(null, null, null);
            ArrayList<ProductosModel> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
            try {
                obj = new JSONArray(response);

                JSONObject jsonArray;

                for (int i = 0; i <= obj.length(); i++) {
                    jsonArray = obj.getJSONObject(i);
                    int id = jsonArray.getInt("id");
                    String codigo = jsonArray.getString("codigo");
                    String descripcion = jsonArray.getString("descripcion");
                    String precio = jsonArray.getString("precio");
                    arrayList.add(new ProductosModel(id, codigo, descripcion, Double.valueOf(precio)));
                }


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }




        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(context, error + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    ) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
            return params;
        }
    };


    Log.d("Resultado ", stringRequest.toString());
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Siempre me da errores de contexto la aplicación.

La inicialización del Recycler View se hace en la misma clase java que donde está el metodo anteriormente expuesto. Les muestro mi Oncreate. es valido resaltar que el método funciona bien al iniciarse la actividad pero no cuando intento llamarlo al tratar de eliminar un producto para que muestre la nueva lista.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_productos);

    context = getApplicationContext();

    //Quitamos barra de notificaciones
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);

    // use this setting to improve performance if you know that changes
    // in content do not change the layout size of the RecyclerView
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    // use a linear layout manager
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    getProductos(context);


    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            finish();
        }
    });

    fab = findViewById(R.id.fabProductos);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Productos.this, NuevoProducto.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


    ocultarFAB(mRecyclerView);

}
```

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged() realiza una recarga del adapter. Pero tienes que actualizar tu lista de objetos Productos. Por ejemplo si eliminas un producto, quitarlo de la lista que pasas al adapter y después llamar al método notifyDataSetChanged().

Comment: Hola muchas gracias ya lo voy a probar porque yo intente usar el notifyDataSetChanged() pero pense que ya lo quitaba el solo de ahi o sea que debo llamar el metodo que carga los productos en el recycler y luego el notifyDataSetChanged().?

Comment: Cuando creas el adapter le pasas unos datos, lo más común es una lista de objetos. Si eliminas un objeto, esa lista tienes que actualizarla y elimnarla de ahí también el elemento.

Comment: me pasa algo similar, pero yo al ejecutar el onclick de un boton dentro del viewholder del recyclerview, Pudiste resolver tu problema?